# Why can´t i update my state property in a superagent request?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, superagent

I have a Button Listener which passes some login informations through a superagent and i get a token returned. Now i would like to update my state property to the received token, which i get correctly. But my this.state.token doesn´t seem to get updated.

Here´s my Code:

```
_btnLoginListener: function () {

    var that = this;
    superAgentRequest
        .post(URL + TOKENS_KEY)
        .type('json')
        .send({ 
            email:    this.state.usernameOrEmail,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .end(function ( err, res ) {
            // Calling the end function will send the superAgentRequest
            if (res.status == 200) {
                /*var token = JSON.parse(res.text).token; // working*/
                /*ToastAndroid.show("POST Response -> " + token, ToastAndroid.SHORT)*/
                that.setState({
                    token: JSON.parse(res.text)
                })
                navigator.replace({
                    id:   'MainController',
                    name: 'MainController',
                });
            } else {
                notifyMessage ("Please check credentials again!")
            }
        })
  }
  notifyMessage (that.state.token)
},
```

Comment: Asynchronous code is asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with not even one but 2 asynchronous processes here:

1. The ajax request is sent and its response runs asynchronously to your current code. Which means the callback is invoked **after** you exit this function
2. `this.setState` does not change it immediately, but schedules the state of the current component to be changed some time later together with it being re-rendered.

What basically means: you're checking `this.state` too early.

Comment: okay thanks. It worked when i called the property in a later position. Do you have any hints to capsulate the superagent and save the token "globally"? I need the token in most of my views, and just passing the props through all my components doesn´t seem nice to me...

Comment: Store it in a store, as it's "recommended" by Flux